# JButton inside a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make `JButton` show inside a `JTextField`. Here's my code (it's not working):

```java
        license = new JTextField();
        license.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                String licenseField = license.getText();
                if(licenseField.isBlank() || licenseField.isEmpty()) {
                    license.setText("Enter your license key");
                    license.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
                }
            }
        });
        license.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                String licenseField = license.getText();
                if(licenseField.equals("Enter your license key")) {
                    license.setText("");
                    license.setForeground(new Color(240, 185, 11));
                }
            }
        });
        license.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                license.setFocusable(true);
            }
        });
        license.setFocusable(false);
        license.setBorder(null);
        Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(240, 185, 11), 1);
        Border Padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 7, 0, 0);
        license.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(lineBorder, BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(license.getBorder(), Padding)));
        license.setText("Enter your license key");
        license.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        license.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        license.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        license.setBounds(115, 248, 370, 60);
        contentPane.add(license);
        license.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
        connect.setFocusPainted(false);
        connect.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        connect.setBorder(null);
        connect.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
        connect.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        connect.setBackground(new Color(240, 185, 11));
        connect.setBounds(369, 255, 109, 46);
        contentPane.add(connect);
```

I ned to show the button inside `JTextField` and make sure when or after the user has typed something the button does not disappear again.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure about the use case. A JTextField is not designed to host a button. Would it help if you render the button over the text field?

Comment: that's not gonna help

Comment: You could use the [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/) approach which allows you to replace the default Border of the text field with a Border that contains a button.

Comment: ComponentBorder is an interesting approach. It might be applicable to SplitButton, where a button has a side button...

Comment: @Hellthinky *The issue is solved.* - then accept the answer that solved the problem or post your own solution.  *Now stuck on another issue* - one question per posting. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting the screenshot as well as your code. Having both makes this much easier to help you.

If you are fine with a slight compromise, then this is very easy to do in Java. Rather than put the button inside of the text field, just make it *look* like the button is inside of the text field. If you are fine with that, here is what you can do.

```java
   private JPanel createContent()
   {
   
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
   
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
      textField.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      textField.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      textField.setText("Enter your license key");
      textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
      textField.addMouseListener(
         new MouseAdapter()
         {
         
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
            {
            
               textField.selectAll();
            
            }
         
         });
      
      final JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      button.setText("Connect");
      
      panel.add(textField);
      panel.add(button);
      
      return panel;
      
   }
```

In the above method, I create a panel, set its background to black, and give it a yellow border. By doing this, I am making that yellow border simulate the border of the text field.

Next, I add my text field to the panel, and remove all decorations that would make the user think that the text field is smaller than the yellow border than above. That means having a black border on a black background.

Finally, I add the button to the panel, then return it.

Here is a complete example.

```java
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SOQ_20230731_1
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      new SOQ_20230731_1();
   
   }
   
   public SOQ_20230731_1()
   {
   
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setSize(300, 100);
      frame.setLocation(100, 100);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      panel.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 40));
      panel.add(createContent());
      
      frame.add(panel);
      
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }
   
   private JPanel createContent()
   {
   
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
   
      final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
      textField.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      textField.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      textField.setText("Enter your license key");
      textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
      textField.addMouseListener(
         new MouseAdapter()
         {
         
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
            {
            
               textField.selectAll();
            
            }
         
         });
      
      final JButton button = new JButton();
      button.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
      button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      button.setText("Connect");
      
      panel.add(textField);
      panel.add(button);
      
      return panel;
      
   }

}
```

And here is a screenshot of what you end up with.

[image: THE SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Your existing code for JTextField (license)...

// Create a JPanel to hold the JTextField and the JButton
JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
textFieldPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

// Add the JTextField to the panel
textFieldPanel.add(license, BorderLayout.CENTER);

// Create a JButton and add it to the panel
JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
connect.setFocusPainted(false);
connect.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
connect.setBorder(null);
connect.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 12));
connect.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
connect.setBackground(new Color(240, 185, 11));
textFieldPanel.add(connect, BorderLayout.EAST);

// Set the preferred size for the panel to adjust the width of the JTextField and the JButton
textFieldPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 60));

// Add the panel to your contentPane
textFieldPanel.setBounds(115, 248, 480, 60);
contentPane.add(textFieldPanel);

// Rest of your code...
```

try this

Comment: Error: Cannot read field "parent" because "comp" is null